# Get the output of a C program without compiling it

Tags: c, windows, cmd, turbo-c

I have a .c file and I have only a Windows command prompt. I have to get the output of the program.

Can the program be compiled without the support of TC or TC3 environment? If so kindly help.

Comment: Are you asking how to compile without a compiler? As in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005219/can-someone-please-explain-how-i-compile-my-code)? Spend some more time formulating your question so we can help you.

Comment: Is C development SDK is installed? Without the SDK or Compiler, Linker and Libraries should be there.... You don't need any IDE to develop a simple C program.

Comment: Do you have a keyboard and a monitor?

Comment: The halting problem says that you can't in general get the output of a C program without (in effect) running it. There exist C interpreters, but for this job I doubt that they have any advantages over a compiler. One way or another you have to run it, so just compile it.

Comment: how to compile without a compiler?? is my question

Comment: Is this some kind of Zen koan? How would you edit text without a text editor? How would you go snorkelling without a snorkel? If you compile the code, then whatever you use to do it would in fact be a compiler, so it is not possible to compile without a compiler.

Comment: What is the sound of a non-program running?

Comment: You can use sites such as http://codepad.org for this

Comment: @Paul, Thanks for the tool reference.  Interesting.

Comment: Valid question, IMNVHO - sometimes we need to compile and run code on platforms where a compiler is not available and/or can not be installed for some reason. Online resources are a useful solution in this kind of situation. Voting to re-open.

Comment: @Paul: as is, the question wants to avoid "compiling the code", not "running a compiler locally".

Comment: Hey and if you arrange for a keyboard and a monitor you'd probably like to begin making your own compiler :P

Comment: @Paul R: ah, well, if the questioner has a *web browser* then all sorts of possibilities open up. Should have said so in the question ;-). +1 on your answer for coming up with something useful.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: well perhaps rashly I assumed that if the OP was able to post a question to SO then there was a high probability that they might have access to a web browser. ;-)

Comment: @Paul: I dread to think what browser they're launching from a DOS prompt. IE 5, maybe?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: or maybe Lynx ? http://lynx.browser.org/

Comment: @Paul: if either of those can handle SO's Javascript, then they're due more credit than I thought.

Comment: @Steve: I'm almost tempted to fire up Lynx and see what happens. ;-)

Comment: Sorry all, what the question meant was without TC or TC3 can the c program be compiled. Probably it can be done with gcc. Thank you all for the suggestions

Comment: Is your goal to get the C program to compile and run under Windows? Or do you actually have MS-DOS (a long obsolete 16-bit operating system) installed somewhere that you could use?

Comment: @RossRidge It is to get the C program compiled and run under windows

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have internet access there are sites such as http://codepad.org which allow you to compile and run small programs in various languages online. Supported languages include C, C++ and many others.

Comment: I'm upvoting for the reference to a nice tool, but this does not comply with the part of the question that says "without *compiling* it". ;)

Comment: @Martinho: strictly speaking you're correct, but I'm interpreting the question as meaning "without a compiler", which may or may not be correct.

Comment: Yep, well done for coming up with an interpretation of the question that isn't daft!

Comment: Sorry all what the question meant was without TC or TC3 can the c program be compiled. Probably it can be done with gcc. Thank you all for the valuable suggestions.

Comment: @soujanya: thank for for following up on your question > 4 years after asking it !

Comment: @Paul: Sorry for the delay !!!

Comment: @soujanya: that's OK - I was just surprised to see a comment after such a long time ! You might want to consider accepting one of the answers now (click on the check mark next to the answer that you found most helpful).

Comment: @Paul: will be regular here on ..sorry Paul I didnt find any check mark next to the answers..!! You provided a very useful tool missed it all these years..!!!!!

Comment: OK - there might not be a check mark visible because the question has been closed. I've voted to re-open it now, but it needs 4 more votes.

Comment: Hope it re-opens soon and thanks for your support...

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a ".c" file, then you don't have a program.  You must compile the program first to make an executable, and then you must run the program to get its output.

Comment: how do i compile that particular file when no compiler is provided to me??

Comment: No compiler is provided to you because they want to see if you can write the code without the assistance of a compiler.  Later, after you submit your solution, they will compile it as a test to see how well you really know the language.

Comment: after verifying the code the output is asked to be shown

Comment: Then this homework is about understanding what the program is supposed to do and figuring out it's outcome. Basically they expect from you, that you run that program in your head. Note that the halting problem does not mean, that the output of no program can be statically determined. It means, that there are programs, for which a statical determination of their output is impossible. But I'm pretty sure the program given to you halts.

Comment: What the question meant was without TC or TC3 can the c program be compiled. Probably it can be done with gcc. Thank you all for the suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You could install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and then compile it using `gcc`.

Comment: Thanq the solution for my question was a gcc compiler. Thank you